# ANTLR: Lexer Throwing NoViableAltException

Tags: antlr, antlr3

After a break of a few weeks, it's time to fight with ANTLR again...

Anyhow, I have the following Lexer tokens defined:

```
fragment EQ: '=';
fragment NE: '<>';

BOOLEAN_FIELD
  : ('ISTRAINED'|'ISCITIZEN')
  ;

BOOLEAN_CONSTANT
  : ('TRUE'|'FALSE'|'Y'|'N')
  ;

BOOLEAN_LOGICAL
  : BOOLEAN_FIELD (EQ|NE) (BOOLEAN_FIELD|BOOLEAN_CONSTANT)
  ;
```

Unfortunately, the BOOLEAN_LOGICAL token is throwning NoViableAltException on simple terms such as "ISTRAINED = ISTRAINED".

I know some of the responses are going to be "This should be in the parser". It WAS previously in the parser, however, I'm trying to offload some simple items into the lexer since I just need a "Yes/No, is this text block valid?"

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you really using double quotes? `"ISTRAINED"` should be `'ISTRAINED'`

Comment: No, that was a "copying example to SO" mistake. The original used single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BOOLEAN_LOGICAL` should not be a lexer rule. A lexer rule must (or should) be a single token. As a lexer rule, there cannot be any spaces between `BOOLEAN_FIELD` and `(EQ|NE)` (you might have skipped spaces during lexing, but that will only cause spaces to be skipped from inside **parser** rules!).

Do this instead:

```
boolean_logical
  : BOOLEAN_FIELD (EQ|NE) (BOOLEAN_FIELD|BOOLEAN_CONSTANT)
  ;
```

which would also mean that `EQ` and `NE` cannot be `fragment` rules anymore:

```
EQ : '=';
NE : '<>';
```

Comment: Also, `EQ` and `NE` should not be `fragment` rules.

Answer (score 1):

This does look like it should be a parser rule.  However, if you want to keep it as a lexer rule, you need to allow whitespace.

```
BOOLEAN_LOGICAL
  : BOOLEAN_FIELD WS+ (EQ|NE) WS+ (BOOLEAN_FIELD|BOOLEAN_CONSTANT)
    ;
```

Comment: If Jason has a `WS` rule defined in which he `skip()`s this token (or puts the token on the `HIDDEN` channel), using this `WS` rule will also cause `BOOLEAN_LOGICAL` to be skipped/hidden.

Comment: I figured that out later. Unfortunately, I have to use so much embedded code (in order to throw custom exceptions instead of the usual NoViableAltException or MismatchedSetException, and what circumstances they are thrown in, etc).